# Skype for Business 2015 : Audio / Video not working in meetings

Tags: audio, dns, skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I'm new to Skype for Business Technology, and I'm trying to deploy a server that I'm willing to use with Skype WebSDK and AppSDK. 
At first I tried using the skype for business online, but the websdk doesn't support the anonymous join to a meeting. So I decided to deploy an on premise version of it.

I followed instructions on this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uNIm5YNIY6Q and also this Document : http://www.msic.ch/Portals/0/Images/Skype%20for%20Business%20Server%202015%20Step%20by%20Step%20for%20Anyone%20-%20Installing%20and%20Upgrading_REV_05.pdf

I have two servers : 
- Active Directory +  Certificat Authority + DNS 
- Skype for Business Standard

The active directory is configured with "contoso.com" and my external domain is also "contoso.com". On the internal DNS I used internal adresses, and on the external DNS I used the public ones. I have an A record for "admin, dialin, meet, sip, lyncdiscover ..."  and SRV record for "_sipinternaltls_tcp" as described on the tutorials.

The installation process was successfull without any error.

My problem is when I create a meeting, I have only the chat without any video or audio. At first the client tries to connect the audio and then hangs up without any errors.

Is there any way to troubleshoot this situation ?  Is there any extra step I should do to activate audio / video in meetings ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you don't have the [CAL licenses](https://products.office.com/en-us/skype-for-business/it-pros) to enable conferencing. The default (free) standard client license doesn't allow conferencing.